# Using localdb with for WF4.5 persistence fails

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, localdb

I am trying to create unit tests for a Workflow that uses SqlWorkflowInstanceStore for it's persistent store. When I try to create and instance I get the following error:

The execution of the InstancePersistenceCommand named {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:System.Activities.Persistence/command}CreateWorkflowOwnerWithIdentity was interrupted by an error.

With the inner error of:

Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

Has anyone have the same a solution for this. When I use SQLEXPRESS using the same dacpac to make sure the schema etc are identical.

Both ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER are OFF.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar errors in the past that were caused by the datatypes I was trying to persist not being compatible with the database.

My first attack on this problem would be to run a workflow that has no arguments and see if it will persist.